# QtConcurrent map() on in place array

Tags: qt, qtconcurrent, qvector

I have a large array of float.
I would like to call `QtConcurrent::map()` on it and change the values in place.

Can I do that without making a copy of the array?
It seems `map()` takes a `QVector` as parameter and I can't find a mean to initialize a `QVector` from an array without making a copy.

Answer (score 1):

QtConcurrent also has versions with STL-style iterators. Raw pointers have the properties of STL-style iterators for this purpose.

```
float x[] = {1.3f, 2.5f, 4.6f};
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::map(x, x+3, [](float & a) { a = 2*a; });
f.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << x[0] << x[1] << x[2];
```

This prints:

```
2.6 5 9.2
```